# SQL Server remove everything from second occurrence till the end

Tags: sql, sql-server, match

I have a column in my SQL Server table that contains text, let's say a row has the following text :

```
"this is a test that was made the year 2012 cause in the year 2013 we was down"
```

What I need is to check if the year occurs more than once; if yes, the text should be updated to be:

```
"this is a test that was made the year 2012 cause in the "
```

so I need to keep everything before the second occurence and delete everything from last occurence till the end

Any help please?

Comment: What range of years would be valid. Is 1973 valid? Is 2199 valid?

Answer (score 1):

This is painful, but you can do it:

```
select (case when col like '%year%year%'
             then left(col,
                       charindex('year', col, charindex('year', col) + 4) - 1
                      )
             else col
        end) as first_year_only
```

Comment: im getting invalid column name , when im inserting the name of the column i want to search in

Comment: @GeorgeNaffah . . . Maybe you missed a place where it needs to be inserted.